# how to implement this in django - back button - keep data in request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am trying to implement this simple but comlicated logic:

user submits the form with given data by clicking on `next`.

in the `next` page, i will show the user what he has given in previous page and ask him to confirm if all what he has given is correct

at this point, user has 2 options.

1. back button
2. finish button

now my problem is, how do I keep the data in request so that the user can press `back` button and gets the form with previuos state with fields filled up. I am thinking about saving all data in hidden inputs in form, in confirm page.

but what is the best way to do things like this in django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a form wizard. You can do it server side by installing django-formtools (which used to be a built-in tool), see:
https://github.com/django/django-formtools/

Or you can do it client side using jquery easily enough using show and hide effects (there are several plugins for it too, for example: http://www.jquery-steps.com/)

Comment: 404...rather post some code than merely links that you do not control

Comment: @surfer190 Edited the answer. I don't like providing links-only answers but sometimes they are the right answer for the question asked. If you're reviewing years-old questions, sometimes those links will need to be updated. A better approach would be to edit the links yourself instead of downvoting.

Comment: Just post the content from the link and all would have been fine from the start.

Comment: @surfer190 A good solution for most cases but it's not really applicable in this specific example. OP didn't understand what he's asking for, I pointed him at the right concept (form-wizard) then I suggested two methods - a built-in tool and a third-side plugin. There's no code example that'll suffice as an answer, nor is there a clear way to copy any content from those links in a usable manner.

Comment: @surfer190 You have to remember that our community guidelines for answers are still guidelines, and they need to be applied in the relevant context. Your knee-jerk responses are meaningless (how do you post the content from a link to a plug-in??) and mostly show how little attention you gave to actually reading anything

Comment: Consider saying: "You can install `django-formtools` and check the [django-formtools documentation](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)". So that the package name is clearly visible and can be searched in a search engine.

Comment: @surfer190 It wasn't a separate package when I answered the question initially, but I edited in a paraphrasing of what you wrote.